# Enable checkbox while click the button in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

The checkbox must be checked while i click the "Accept" button.

HTML

```
<input id="eulacheckbox" dojoType='dijit.form.CheckBox' data-dojo-props='checked: false' />
<button class="defaultButton" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" id="eulaAccept">Accept</button>
```

Dojo

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId("eulaAccept"), "onClick", function(){
    dijit.byId("eulacheckbox"),set("data-dojo-props", "checked: true");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the property `checked` in the `CheckBox dijit` just set it to `true`

```
registry.byId("eulaAccept").on("click",function(){
    registry.byId("eulacheckbox").set("checked",true)
});
```

Hee is a fiddle : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjore5sm/3/)

Answer (score 2):

this seems to work just fine using the `dojo.attr` method:

```
var eulaAccept = dojo.byId("eulaAccept");
var eulaCheckbox = dojo.byId("eulacheckbox");

dojo.connect(eulaAccept, "onclick", function(evt) {
    dojo.attr(eulaCheckbox, 'data-dojo-props', 'checked: true');
});
```

see the doc for more info: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/attr.html